# How to create a generic input element with a required flag using react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm looping over an array to create html input elements? How can I specify if the component is required (generically)?

Here is the list:

```
formInputs: [
  {
    name: 'title',
    type: 'text',
  },
  {
    name: 'first_name',
    type: 'text',
    required: true
  }
]
```

And here is the function that builds / returns the elements:
...

```
{formInputs.map(o => this.renderInput(o))}

renderInput = input => {
return (
 <FormInput
  name={input.name}
  type={input.type}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
  value={this.state.formValues[input.name]}
  required={input.required}
 />
 )
}
```

The `required` property is not set correctly

Comment: Where is `FormInput` coming from?

Comment: This is happening because the key 'required' is not there in every object of the array. Try to add the key 'required' in all objects and If the field id not required then put its value as false.

Answer (score 0):

provide `required` key for all object and keep it `false`.

formInputs: [
  {
    name: 'title',
    type: 'text',
    required: false 
  },
  {
    name: 'first_name',
    type: 'text',
    required: true
  }
]